# Sorting LWJGL in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm having a problem with LWJGL and I just can't seem to find a working solution. I'm developing a game for my university project and when I run the 'SimpleGame' code, I keep getting this error: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path'

I have been looking for a solution for weeks and it just doesn't seem to want to work. I've copied the jar files to a 'lib' folder within my project and created a folder for the natives which contain the necessary DLLs and I've put everything in my build path and tried multiple combinations of VM arguments.

I'm at my wits end with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your VM arguments. Mind posting them along with the IDE you're using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Indigo and the arguments I'm using are:
-Djava.library.path="lib/jar"
-Djava.library.path="lib/natives"

Comment: After playing around with my VM arguments, I managed to get it to work with absolute paths, but I would like it to work with the files within my project. My current VM arguments are as follows, but some of these may be incorrect/unnecessary.
-Djava.library.path="C:\Slick+LWJGL\lwjgl-2.8.5"

-Djava.library.path="C:\Slick+LWJGL\lwjgl-2.8.5\jar"

-Djava.library.path="C:\Slick+LWJGL\lwjgl-2.8.5\native"

-Djava.library.path="C:\Slick+LWJGL\lwjgl-2.8.5\native\windows"
OS is Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. I copied the 'lwjgl' folder (containing docs, jars, natives folders, etc) into a folder within my project called 'lib'. I hope this helps someone else in future as I've been trying to find a working solution to this for ages.

I edited my VM arguments so they looked like this (can't post a screenshot because I don't have enough rep yet):

-Djava.library.path="lib\lwjgl"

-Djava.library.path="lib\lwjgl\jar"

-Djava.library.path="lib\lwjgl\native"

-Djava.library.path="lib\lwjgl\native\windows"

I also made sure that 'lwjgl.jar' and 'slick.jar' were added to my build path.
Again, I hope this helps! Many thanks to @Crynix for advising me to check my VM arguments.